# Node distance command not working

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

I am trying to make the tables closer to the nodes by specifying `node distance`.

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows.meta, positioning}
\tikzset{
    events/.style={ellipse, draw, align=center},
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]\centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, >= Stealth, shorten >= 1pt]
        \node [events] (A) {$A$};
        \node [events, below left = of A] (C) {$C$};
        \node [events, below right = of A] (D) {$D$};
        \node [events, above right = of D] (B) {$B$};
        
        \draw [->] (A) -- (C);
        \draw [->] (A) -- (D);
        \draw [->] (B) -- (D);
        
        \node [above left = of A, node distance = 1cm] {
            \begin{tabular}{CC}
            \mathrm{P(A=F)} & \mathrm{P(A=T)}\\
            \hline
            0.9 & 0.1\\
            \end{tabular}
        };
        
        \node [above right = of B,node distance = 1cm] {
            \begin{tabular}{CC}
            \mathrm{P(B=F)} & \mathrm{P(B=T)}\\
            \hline
            0.5 & 0.5\\
            \end{tabular}
        };
        
        \node [below left = of C,node distance = 1cm] {
            \begin{tabular}{c|CC}
            A & \mathrm{P(C=F)} & \mathrm{P(C=T)}\\
            \hline
            F & 0.8 & 0.2\\
            T & 0.3 & 0.7\\
            \end{tabular}
        };
        
        \node [below right = of D, node distance = 1cm] {
            \begin{tabular}{cc|CC}
            A & B & \mathrm{P(D=F)} & \mathrm{P(D=T)}\\
            \hline
            F & F & 0.7 & 0.3\\
            T & F & 0.3 & 0.7\\
            F & T & 0.4 & 0.6\\
            T & T & 0.1 & 0.9\\
            \end{tabular}
        }; 
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

The `node distance` command doesn't have any effect on the tables' positions relative to the nodes.

Comment: You can either say `\node [ node distance = 1cm,below right = of D]...`, i.e. set the `node distance` before, or `\node [below right =1cm and 0.5cm of D]...`.

Comment: Have you tried [inner sep=0pt]?  The inner sep is part of the node itself and doesn't count.

Comment: Nope I haven’t thought about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `node distance` key has an effect if you set it *before* keys like `below right=`. You can also say something like

```
\node [below right =1cm and 0.5cm of D]...
```

where one can set two distances, vertical and horizontal.

However, you seem to want to set all node distances to a smaller value when you start placing the tabulars. Then it makes sense to just place a

```
 \tikzset{node distance = 0.6cm and 0.5cm}
```

in the `tikzpicture`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows.meta, positioning}
\tikzset{
    events/.style={ellipse, draw, align=center},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, >= Stealth, shorten >= 1pt]
     \node [events] (A) {$A$};
     \node [events, below left = of A] (C) {$C$};
     \node [events, below right = of A] (D) {$D$};
     \node [events, above right = of D] (B) {$B$};

     \draw [->] (A) -- (C);
     \draw [->] (A) -- (D);
     \draw [->] (B) -- (D);
     \tikzset{node distance = 0.6cm and 0.5cm}
     \node [above left = of A] {
         \begin{tabular}{CC}
         \mathrm{P(A=F)} & \mathrm{P(A=T)}\\
         \hline
         0.9 & 0.1\\
         \end{tabular}
     };

     \node [above right = of B] {
         \begin{tabular}{CC}
         \mathrm{P(B=F)} & \mathrm{P(B=T)}\\
         \hline
         0.5 & 0.5\\
         \end{tabular}
     };

     \node [below left = of C] {
         \begin{tabular}{c|CC}
         A & \mathrm{P(C=F)} & \mathrm{P(C=T)}\\
         \hline
         F & 0.8 & 0.2\\
         T & 0.3 & 0.7\\
         \end{tabular}
     };

     \node [below right = of D] {
         \begin{tabular}{cc|CC}
         A & B & \mathrm{P(D=F)} & \mathrm{P(D=T)}\\
         \hline
         F & F & 0.7 & 0.3\\
         T & F & 0.3 & 0.7\\
         F & T & 0.4 & 0.6\\
         T & T & 0.1 & 0.9\\
         \end{tabular}
     }; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does `{node distance = 0.6cm and 0.5cm}` refer to x and y direction, respectively?

Comment: Also, it's quite interesting that I have to put `node distance` before `*orientation* = of...`

Comment: @Superman It is first `y` and then `x`. The thing is that for positioning you should either set the node distance outside the path or with something like `below=3mm of...`.

Comment: Hmmmmm interesting. Thank you for your answer, though!